# Can't ping to computer but reverse ping can

Tags: windows, internet, ping, subnet, ipv4

So Computer 1 can ping to computer 2 but reverse it can't

Setup:

Router A (192.168.0.xxx) 255.255.255.0 > Router B (192.168.1.xxx) 255.255.255.0

So computer1 on Router B can ping to computer2 on router A but reverse can't.
Router B has a static IP adress (192.168.0.xxx).

Windows firewalls on both PC's are off. On both of the routers as well.

Can someone help?

Comment: 192.168.x.x is a local/private IP address; your routers have NAT - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation - separating you from the rest of the world... you'd need to port forward for ping to a machine behind NAT to work, otherwise only the router itself would even possibly respond, & not to a 192.168.x.x ping

Comment: I don't get it, both routers are on the same network. I'm trying to ping computer1 to computer2 on the same network ?

Comment: check for ICMP block in system
are you using windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow computers in the 192.168.0.x LAN to ping computers in the 192.168.1.x LAN, routerB must be configured to forward ICMP traffic between its WAN and LAN.

To do this, go to [portforward.com](http://portforward.com/), and search for instructions by routerB's model number. they have instructions for most common router models. configure routerB's NAT to allow ICMP echo packets, and you should then be able to ping inbound to routerB's LAN.

To understand whats happening, you must first understand that your computers are not on the same LAN, so in order to ping each other, routerB must pass the traffic between them.  Your router however, sounds like a standard home/small-office router, which implements a pair of technologies called [Stateful Packet Inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall), and [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Every router has at least two networks, its inside (LAN), and its outside (WAN; everything outside the LAN, from its perspective). from routerA's perspective, its WAN is your ISPs network and the Internet at large, and its LAN is everything in the 192.168.0.x/24 network. routerB's LAN is the 192.168.1.x/24 network, and its WAN is routerA's LAN, the ISP netowrk, and everything else outside its LAN. So computers in routerA's LAN are in routerB's WAN.

NAT and SPI generally allow all hosts inside the LAN to connect to computers on the outside, and receive responses to those connections, but it prevents a computer on the WAN from initiating a connection to a computer on the LAN. This is why you can ping from 192.168.1.x (routerB's LAN) outward to 192.168.0.x(routerA's LAN and routerB's WAN). It is also why a computer in the routerB's WAN cannot connect inbound to a computer in routerB's LAN. You can however create a forwarding rule in NAT that allows specific types of connections to pass through the SPI, and initiate connections on the inside.

see more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: Cant really find it, Router B is Linksys E1000

Comment: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/default.htm

Comment: It looks like your router does not support port forwarding for ICMP applications, so use this guide: http://www.ehow.com/how_8504133_enable-wan-ping-linksys-router.html

Comment: That was already unchecked ... what now ..

Comment: on the same page disable SPI firewall. that MAY allow pings. ultimately, since your router is in the middle of the LAN, its safe to disable the firewall, but most routers don't give you the option to do so completely. better yet to use Bridge mode, but it doesn't look like your router supports that either. you may be able to cascade however: http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?vw=1&docid=785463d9ecaf4cac84aed245b08d615f_3733.xml&pid=80&respid=0&snid=1&dispid=0&cpage=search